# How to install a package in stack which is not currently in any LTS snapshots?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install the fallowing packages, but both failed.

- https://www.stackage.org/package/vacuum-cairo
- https://www.stackage.org/package/SourceGraph

I'm running `stack Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 x86_64 hpack-0.15.0` on windows 10.

I tried `resolver: ghc-8.0.2` and `resolver: ghc-7.8.4`, but none of them works.

PS: I have tried to add extra-deps step by step, and still failed at last, the `stack.yaml` file and the error message is noted [here](https://gist.github.com/luochen1990/4a50c5c10e521939cf8806dc39b1265b)

Comment: Add it your cabal dependencies, and stack should tell you what to do.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/) - in particular you will probably want to specify the dependencies in the `extra-deps` field.

Comment: thx, but after add all the dependencies step by step, it still failed at last ...

Answer (score 1):

Clear the `extra-deps` list in `stack.yaml`, change the resolver to `lts-3.22`, run `stack solver --update-config` (which should automatically add *vacuum-cairo*, *SourceGraph* and possibly a few other packages to the `extra-deps`) and run `stack build` for your project (assuming the dependencies in your .cabal file are correctly declared, there is no need to run a separate `stack install $PACKAGE`). That will likely do it.

The set of packages provided in coordination (i.e. per-user, as opposed to per-project, and with compatibility guarantees) by `ghc-*` resolvers is much smaller than that of snapshot resolvers (be them LTS or nightly), which makes them unnecessarily inconvenient. Broadly speaking, the only good reason for using a `ghc-*` resolver is if there is no snapshot resolver with the version of GHC you want to use, which is not the case here.

I picked the somewhat old `lts-3.22` because it is the last resolver offering *Cabal* 1.22 and *haskell-src-exts* 1.16, versions required by *SourceGraph*. (In principle, you could try using a custom version of *SourceGraph* with more liberal version bounds, or give the `allow-newer` option of Stack a shot, but I guess that in this specific case the odds of failure are high, as given the package description *SourceGraph* is probably quite sensitive to changes in GHC.) I found the versions of the packages offered by the snapshot by going to [its page in the Stackage site](https://www.stackage.org/lts-3.22).

Comment: `Clear the extra-deps list in stack-yaml`, you mean the `stack.yaml` of global project?

Comment: I'm not install this package as a dependency of my package,  I'm installing it as a command line tool. What should I do to install it as a command line tool without `stack new` an empty project?

Comment: (1) Yup -- I did mean `stack.yaml` (the hyphen was a typo), and the global project file is the relevant one if you aren't working in the context of a project. (2) If *SourceGraph* were in Stackage, something like `stack install SourceGraph --resolver lts-3.2.2` would work. As it is not, I suggest `stack unpack SourceGraph` (to get the source tree of the package), followed by `stack init` (to create a `stack.yaml` file), then by fixing the resolver and dependencies as suggested above, and finally `stack install`. (I will look into tweaking this answer later on.)

Comment: I'm using `stack init --solver` and it failed with the deps version confliction, and the stack.yaml is not generated, so there is no pos I can add `allow-newer` option, and I tried `stack init --solver --allow-newer` but now working.

Comment: @luochen1990 If you haven't tried it yet, I suggest `stack init --solver --resolver lts-3.2.2`.

Comment: I tried `stack init --solver --resolver lts-3.22` , and an error contains `Unable to start C:\Users\Luo\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.2\mingw\bin/realgcc.exe (error code: 2)` is reported

Comment: @luochen1990 That appears to be an unrelated issue. [Stack issue #3189](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3189) seems relevant.